# `col-*` not working in Bootstrap 5 - angular2

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-5

Can't figure out why the columns aren't being structured with this HTML component:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if i use col-someNumber, it does not work
[columns displaying incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnYLD.png)

But if i use the class 'col', it works.
[columns displaying correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/621Qa.png)

this is my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Product } from '../model/product.model';
import { ProductService } from './product.service.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css', '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css']
})
```

I need one columns smaller than the other, that's why i don't use '.col'.
'.col-*' should do the work.
I also replaced my html with multiple bootstrap .col-* examples, but none seems to work

Comment: Have you inspected the CSS and "Elements" tab in the dev tools? What does it show?

Comment: @Carcigenicate [here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awJWA.png)

Comment: They're crossed out, so something is overriding them. Find an entry above that that overrides both, or go to the "Computed" tab and see where it's getting the `flex` and `width` values from.

Comment: [looks like .row is generating the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu3XZ.png). But isn't the row class necessary to use the .col class?